# javascript, canvas, how to crop and rotate sprites

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation, crop

Have working code to crop sprites

```
draw() {
const cropWidth = this.image.width / this.frames.max;
const crop = {
  position: {
    x: cropWidth * this.frames.current,
    y: 0,
  },
  width: cropWidth,
  height: this.image.height,
};

const canvasMap = document.getElementById("canvasGame");
const cMap = canvasMap.getContext("2d");

cMap.drawImage(
  this.image,
  crop.position.x,
  crop.position.y,
  crop.width,
  crop.height,
  this.position.x + this.offset.x,
  this.position.y + this.offset.y,
  crop.width,
  crop.height
);
```

}

Have working code to rotate images

```
    function drawRotated(image, cMap, center, degrees) {
  // cMap.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  cMap.save();
  cMap.translate(center.x, center.y);
  cMap.rotate((degrees * Math.PI) / 180);
  cMap.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.width / 2);
  cMap.restore();
}
```

Have code to calculate angle of enemy in corelation to tower

```
    function Angle(center, target) {
  var dy = target.y - center.y;
  var dx = target.x - center.x;
  var theta = Math.atan2(dy, dx); // range (-PI, PI]
  theta *= 180 / Math.PI; // rads to degs, range (-180, 180]
  //if (theta < 0) theta = 360 + theta; // range [0, 360)
  return theta;
}
```

Issue is, i'm unable to figure out how to rotate cropped sprites, whatever im trying, it all gets messed up.

Is there a way to merge draw function code and drawRotated function code, so i could rotate cropped sprites dynamically.

You can check what i have working till now, 3 different towers, some actively follow enemy, but cropped one, which i need for animation, doesn't.

https://piano-flashcards.github.io/td-poker/

Comment: Your drawRotated code translates to the center of the place where the image is drawn, rotates around that and then draws the image with a negative offset of half the image size, which is the usual way of doing that. Are you doing the same thing with your cropped image?

Comment: Cropped image is also positioned into the centter of drawn area

Comment: Have you translated to the point around which you want to rotate, before either calling drawImage with negative the size of the image or translating back.

Comment: Yes, still didnt got it working, so nstead i cropped sripes in inkscape and use them like that, works for now, will return to it later on.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Was reading online about some issues with crop and rotate while being used together, on github `https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1138` seen recomendation in similar case to rather use transform than rotate, with transform it seems everything is working just fine for now.

```
  cMap.save();
  cMap.translate(center.x, center.y);
  cMap.transform(
    Math.cos((degrees * Math.PI) / 180),
    Math.sin((degrees * Math.PI) / 180),
    -Math.sin((degrees * Math.PI) / 180),
    Math.cos((degrees * Math.PI) / 180),
    0,
    0
  );
  cMap.drawImage(
    image,
    0,
    0,
    image.width / 8,
    image.width,
    -image.width / 8 / 2,
    -image.height / 2,
    image.width / 8,
    image.width
  );

  cMap.restore();
```